# One Eloquent model from multiple databases

Tags: php, database, eloquent

I'm working on a use case where one Eloquent Model should be found in multiple databases (eg. from different installations of an application).

The only way I can think of is using a super class and inherit from it with different `protected $connection = 'database_connection'`'s. Like this:

```
class SuperModel extends Model
{
   ...
}

class SubModel1 extends SuperModel
{
   protected $connection = 'connection_1';
   ...
}

class SubModel2 extends SuperModel
{
   protected $connection = 'connection_2';
   ...
}
```

Is this the correct way to go or am I missing some Eloquent functionality that allows for this?

Comment: Yes this is right way

Comment: Thanks, sometimes an answer can be that simple..